# Cockroach Write Performance

Tags: h2, cockroachdb

I deployed a one node cockroach database. No tuning whatsoever. The command is:

```
cockroach start --insecure --host=0.0.0.0
```

Inserting data into the database takes in average 400 ms. I made about 10000 requests with about 10 requests per seconds.

I took the the very same test script and inserted the same data set into H2 (not embedded). The H2 is running on the very same node that cockroach is running on. The client machine is exactly the same. With H2, I get average of 7ms to write to the database.

I presume this is not right. Anything I should do to setup cockoach properly?

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that you're also working with this on the forum, I'm linking that issue here so others can follow along: https://forum.cockroachlabs.com/t/cockroach-write-performance/1741/14

tl;dr: 400ms is not expected for an individual insert, and we couldn't reproduce the issue testing locally or in the cloud. This also couldn't be reproduced on EC2, leading us to suspect that the slow performance was related to something specific to the box.